# React page not rendering with all elements and no header

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page in my react site that will load an option box of values retrieved from the server and when the user selects an item from the box, I then make another call to the server for different data (file names and a URL to download the file).

What I can't get working is two things 1) when I select an item from the box, I get to a new page that doesn't have my header and other items that show after the render() call.  2) I can iterate through my array and get the items I need but none of my href links show.

```
  itemSelect(event){

    params.fileName= event.currentTarget[1].name

    restAPI.put(`/api/customers/files`, {params: event.nativeEvent.srcElement.value}).then(res =>{

      const element = (
        <div>
        {Object.entries(res.data).forEach(key => {
           if(key[1].name.length > 0){
                console.log('url', key[1].url)
                console.log('name', key[1].name)
          return <a href={key[1].url}>{key[1].name}</a>
           }
        })}
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
           <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
        );

      return ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));

      })
    }

  render() {
       const { folderList = {} } = this.state;

      return (
      <div id="root">
      <select name='folderListing' onChange={this.itemSelect.bind(this)}>
      {Object.values(folderList).map(function(item) {
         return <option key={item} name={item} id={item} value={item}>{item} </option>
      })}
      </select>
      </div>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing your elements because of this line:

```
return ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You are effectively replacing your entire app with `element`. Instead, use the returned `element` in your `render` method:

```
state = {
  links: null,
  folderList: {}
};

itemSelect(event){

  params.fileName= event.currentTarget[1].name

  restAPI.put(`/api/customers/files`, {params: event.nativeEvent.srcElement.value}).then(res =>{

    const element = (
      <div>
        {Object.entries(res.data).forEach(key => {
          if(key[1].name.length > 0){
            console.log('url', key[1].url)
            console.log('name', key[1].name)
            return <a href={key[1].url}>{key[1].name}</a>
          }
        })}
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );

    this.setState({
      links: element
    });

  });
}

render() {
  const { folderList = {}, links } = this.state;

  return (
    <div id="root">
      <select name='folderListing' onChange={this.itemSelect.bind(this)}>
        {Object.values(folderList).map(function(item) {
          return <option key={item} name={item} id={item} value={item}>{item} </option>
        })}
      </select>
      {links}
    </div>
  )
}
```